# Assigning Records via a trigger on User Object

Tags: apex, trigger, user-management, user-record

Aim-

In this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrtVN8vZGJU you can see that “Jim Smith” is going through the  de-activation process . What i want to do, is when you press save, an apex trigger  is triggered and automatically re-assigns “Jim Smith” Leads into this appropriate manager

Having a quick look, it looks like I can create a trigger on the User object. However i am new to this, so i may be mistaken

Looking for any help/advice

Regards
D

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create triggers on the User object.

Also from Winter 14 you can create workflow rules and actions on User too.

Create a User trigger by going to Setup | Customize | Users | Triggers

[image: User trigger]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Do you know where i can find a dummy guide to writing the apex code i need for the following ?

Comment: You can look at the quickstart coding guide http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_trigger.htm

Comment: Hi Thank you for the link. I do have one question , what would my trigger execute on ? would it be when the records are updated ?

Comment: I would imagine for your scenario you would want a trigger on User object, before update, and looking for records where isActive is changing from true to false

Comment: I would argue AFTER UPDATE, to ensure that the de-activation succeeded.

Comment: HI Mike Chale , thank you for your advice. Learning this apex language is complicated :(